# Proverb about the origin of the English language

Tags: phrase-requests, proverbs

Is there a nice proverb that highlights the foreign (e.g. German and French) origins of the English language?

I remember that I've once read something like

> English is the bastard child of a German mother, French father and...

But I can't seem to find the source.

Comment: "English is a love child of PIE and, um, more PIE."

Comment: None could be both pithy enough to be a proverb and accurate enough to be of any use.

Comment: Whatever the English language might be, relating it to any languages by descriptions like "be a bastard" does nothing except that it lowers its dignity. It has been accepted as an international language either it would be a bastard of other languages or an independent language. Do you know a pure language? If so, what is it?

Comment: “The problem with defending the purity of the English language is that the English language is as pure as a crib-house whore. It not only borrows words from other languages; it has on occasion chased other languages down dark alley-ways, clubbed them unconscious and rifled their pockets for new vocabulary.” ― James Nicoll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.jamshid-ibrahim.net/74.0.html) thanks to Google.

> What is English?  ...
>
> - A child who was born to a German mother  with a French step-father and has some Scandinavian blood (...)

Comment: Little do they know that [Scandinavian languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Germanic_languages) are Germanic, too. It's worse than Barrie predicted — *neither* pithy enough to be a proverb *nor* accurate enough to be of any use.